# STM32F4Discovery: Receiving CAN message

Tags: arm, can-bus, stm32f4discovery

I am lost on how to receive CAN message on [STM32F4Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Discovery_boards). I have it in Silent_Loopback mode, meaning all sent messages should arrive in CAN controller itself. I get Transmit_OK status when I send the message, however, nothing appears in the FIFO mailbox. I have skipped CAN filter configuration in order to receive all messages and not to filter any of them out. What am I doing wrong?

```
/* Includes */
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4_discovery.h"

void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount) {
    while(nCount--) {
    }
}

void RCC_Configuration(void) {
    /* ENABLE CLOCKS         */
    /* GPIOB clock enable    */
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

    /* USART3 clock enable   */
       RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART3, ENABLE);
    /* CAN1 clock enable     */
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_CAN1, ENABLE);

    /* CAN2 clock enable     */
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_CAN2, ENABLE);
}

void GPIO_Configuration(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructureUSART;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructureCAN_RX;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX;

    /* GPIO USART Configuration */
    GPIO_InitStructureUSART.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11;
    GPIO_InitStructureUSART.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructureUSART.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructureUSART.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructureUSART.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructureUSART);

    /* Connect USART to AF */
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_USART3); //USART_TX = PB10
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_USART3); //USART_RX = PB11

    /* GPIO CAN_RX Configuration */
    GPIO_InitStructureCAN_RX.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12;
    GPIO_InitStructureCAN_RX.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    //GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    //GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    //GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructureCAN_RX);

    /* GPIO CAN_TX Configuration */
    GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13;
    GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructureCAN_TX);

    /* Connect CAN_RX & CAN_TX to AF9 */
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_CAN2); //CAN_RX = PB12
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_CAN2); //CAN_TX = PB13
}

void USART_Configuration(void) {
    USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

    /* USART3 configuration */
    /* 256000 baud, window 8 data bits, one stop bit, no parity, no hardware flow control, rx/tx enabled */
    USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 256000;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
    USART_Init(USART3, &USART_InitStructure);

    USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);
}

void CAN_Configuration(void) {
    CAN_InitTypeDef CAN_InitStructure;

    /* CAN2 reset */
    CAN_DeInit(CAN2);

    /* CAN2 configuration */
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_TTCM = DISABLE; // Time-triggered communication mode = DISABLED
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_ABOM = DISABLE; // Automatic bus-off management mode = DISABLED
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_AWUM = DISABLE; // Automatic wake-up mode = DISABLED
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_NART = DISABLE; // Non-automatic retransmission mode = DISABLED
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_RFLM = DISABLE; // Receive FIFO locked mode = DISABLED
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_TXFP = DISABLE; // Transmit FIFO priority = DISABLED
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Mode = CAN_Mode_Silent_LoopBack; // Normal CAN mode
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_SJW = CAN_SJW_1tq; // Synchronization jump width = 1
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS1 = CAN_BS1_14tq; //14
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS2 = CAN_BS2_6tq;  //6
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Prescaler = 4;      // Baudrate 500 kbps
    //CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Prescaler = 16;   // Baudrate 125 kbps
    if (CAN_Init(CAN2, &CAN_InitStructure)) { // Initialize CAN
        STM_EVAL_LEDInit(LED6); // Initialize and
        STM_EVAL_LEDOn(LED6);   // Turn ON blue LED if CAN initialization is successful
    }
}

void CAN_FilterConfiguration(void) {
    CAN_FilterInitTypeDef CAN_FilterInitStructure;

    /* CAN2 filter configuration */
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterNumber = 0; // Filter number = 0 (0<=x<=13)
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMode = CAN_FilterMode_IdMask; // Filter mode = identifier mask based filtering
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterScale = CAN_FilterScale_16bit;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdHigh = 0x0300 << 5; //0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x03FF << 5;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FIFO0; // FIFO = 0
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterActivation = ENABLE;
    CAN_FilterInit(&CAN_FilterInitStructure);
}

void CAN_TxMessage(void) {
    CanTxMsg TxMessage;

    /* CAN message to send */
    TxMessage.StdId = 0x321;
    TxMessage.ExtId = 0x01;
    TxMessage.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    TxMessage.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
    TxMessage.DLC = 8;
    TxMessage.Data[0] = 0x04;
    TxMessage.Data[1] = 0x01;
    TxMessage.Data[2] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[3] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[4] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[5] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[6] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[7] = 0x00;

    //while (1) {
        CAN_TransmitStatus(CAN2, 0);
        CAN_Transmit(CAN2, &TxMessage);
        if(CAN_TransmitStatus(CAN2, 0)){
            STM_EVAL_LEDInit(LED4); // Initialize and
            STM_EVAL_LEDOn(LED4);   // turn ON green LED if transmit was successful
        }
    //}
}

void CAN_OBDII_RequestCurrentData(int PIDNumber) {
    CanTxMsg TxMessage;

    TxMessage.StdId = 0x7DF; // PID request identifier
    TxMessage.ExtId = 0x7DF;
    TxMessage.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    TxMessage.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
    TxMessage.DLC = 8;
    TxMessage.Data[0] = 0x02; // Number of additional bytes = 2
    TxMessage.Data[1] = 0x01; // Show current data = 1
    TxMessage.Data[2] = PIDNumber; // PID code number
    TxMessage.Data[3] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[4] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[5] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[6] = 0x00;
    TxMessage.Data[7] = 0x00;

    CAN_Transmit(CAN2, &TxMessage); // Transmit OBDII PID request via CAN2/mailbox0
}

void CAN_RxMessage(void) {
    CanRxMsg RxMessage;
    int d0=0;
    while(1) {
        CAN_Receive(CAN2,CAN_FIFO0,&RxMessage);

        d0 = RxMessage.Data[0];
        d0 = RxMessage.Data[1];
        d0 = RxMessage.Data[2];
        d0 = RxMessage.Data[3];
        d0 = RxMessage.Data[4];
        d0 = RxMessage.Data[5];
        d0 = RxMessage.Data[6];
        d0 = RxMessage.Data[7];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize Clocks */
    RCC_Configuration();

    /* Initialize GPIO */
    GPIO_Configuration();

    /* Initialize USART */
    USART_Configuration();

    /* Initialize CAN */
    CAN_Configuration();

    /* Initialize CAN Reception Filter */
    //CAN_FilterConfiguration();

    /* Transfer CAN message */
    CAN_TxMessage();

    /* Receive CAN message */
    CAN_RxMessage();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure filter to accept all messages (if you don't have any filter, no message will be accepted). But in your example you use CAN2, so FilterNumber must be 14 or higher.

```
#define CAN_FIFO_ID                0
#define CAN_FIFO                   CAN_FIFO0
#define CAN_FIFO_IN                CAN_IT_FMP0

/**
* @brief Default filter - accept all to CAN_FIFO
*/
void CAN_SetFilter()
{
    /* Default filter - accept all to CAN_FIFO*/
    CAN_FilterInitTypeDef CAN_FilterInitStructure;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterNumber = 14; // 0..13 for CAN1, 14..27 for CAN2
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FIFO;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMode = CAN_FilterMode_IdMask;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterScale = CAN_FilterScale_16bit;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_FIFO_ID;
    CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterActivation = ENABLE;
    CAN_FilterInit(&CAN_FilterInitStructure);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of filters assigned to CAN1 and CAN2 is defined in the CAN_FMR register which by default is set to 14 which is the start of the CAN2 filters.

This can be set to 28 which would mean no filters to CAN2 and all 28 to CAN1 or if set to 0 all 28 filters are assigned to CAN2.

Answer (score 0):

Normally (if you have a valid Filter Number) in mask mode any mask = zero will let everything through.